# Cannot get basic SimpleModal & ASP.NET MVC 2 working :( Help

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

All i wanna do is get the basic demo for SimpleModal working with ASP.NET MVC 2, i get weird behavior...

What im doing is basically copying the index.html from the demo, to the Index.aspx body of my /Home..so it looks like this:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id='container'>
 <div id='logo'>
  <h1>Simple<span>Modal</span></h1>
  <span class='title'>A Modal Dialog Framework Plugin for jQuery</span>
 </div>
 <div id='content'>
  <div id='basic-modal'>
   <h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3>
   <p>A basic modal dialog with minimal styling and no additional options. There are a few CSS properties set internally by SimpleModal, however, SimpleModal relies mostly on style options and/or external CSS for the look and feel.</p>
   <input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic'/> or <a href='#' class='basic'>Demo</a>
  </div>

  <!-- modal content -->
  <div id="basic-modal-content">
   <h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3>
   <p>For this demo, SimpleModal is using this "hidden" data for its content. You can also populate the modal dialog with an AJAX response, standard HTML or DOM element(s).</p>
   <p>Examples:</p>
   <p><code>$('#basicModalContent').modal(); // jQuery object - this demo</code></p>
   <p><code>$.modal(document.getElementById('basicModalContent')); // DOM</code></p>
   <p><code>$.modal('&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;HTML&lt;/b&gt; elements&lt;/p&gt;'); // HTML</code></p>
   <p><code>$('&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;').load('page.html').modal(); // AJAX</code></p>

   <p><a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/'>More details...</a></p>
  </div>

  <!-- preload the images -->
  <div style='display:none'>
   <img src='img/basic/x.png' alt='' />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id='footer'>
  &copy; 2010 Eric Martin | <a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/'>ericmmartin.com</a> | <a href='http://twitter.com/ericmmartin'>@ericmmartin</a> | <a href='http://twitter.com/simplemodal'>@simplemodal</a>
 </div>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

And in my Site.Master i include all the js files from the demo:

```
<head runat="server">
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<!-- Load jQuery, SimpleModal and Basic JS files -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/basic.js'></script>
```

I think it finds all of them just fine..but it doesnt work..heres the source once its run:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

    Home Page

</title><link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!-- Load jQuery, SimpleModal and Basic JS files -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/Scripts/basic.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">

        [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]

            </div> 

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">

    <div id='container'>
 <div id='logo'>
  <h1>Simple<span>Modal</span></h1>
  <span class='title'>A Modal Dialog Framework Plugin for jQuery</span>
 </div>
 <div id='content'>
  <div id='basic-modal'>
   <h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3>
   <p>A basic modal dialog with minimal styling and no additional options. There are a few CSS properties set internally by SimpleModal, however, SimpleModal relies mostly on style options and/or external CSS for the look and feel.</p>
   <input type='button' name='basic' value='Demo' class='basic'/> or <a href='#' class='basic'>Demo</a>
  </div>

  <!-- modal content -->
  <div id="basic-modal-content">
   <h3>Basic Modal Dialog</h3>
   <p>For this demo, SimpleModal is using this "hidden" data for its content. You can also populate the modal dialog with an AJAX response, standard HTML or DOM element(s).</p>
   <p>Examples:</p>
   <p><code>$('#basicModalContent').modal(); // jQuery object - this demo</code></p>
   <p><code>$.modal(document.getElementById('basicModalContent')); // DOM</code></p>
   <p><code>$.modal('&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;HTML&lt;/b&gt; elements&lt;/p&gt;'); // HTML</code></p>
   <p><code>$('&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;').load('page.html').modal(); // AJAX</code></p>

   <p><a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/'>More details...</a></p>
  </div>

  <!-- preload the images -->
  <div style='display:none'>
   <img src='img/basic/x.png' alt='' />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id='footer'>
  &copy; 2010 Eric Martin | <a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/'>ericmmartin.com</a> | <a href='http://twitter.com/ericmmartin'>@ericmmartin</a> | <a href='http://twitter.com/simplemodal'>@simplemodal</a>
 </div>
</div>



            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyything look weird? Am i missing something?

Comment: "I get weird behavior. Here's ALL my code. What's wrong?" A very lazy question.

Comment: Like an idiot - i forgot to put the page styles that simplemodal uses - but one problem - the "X" to close it out is gone...any idea there?

Comment: Download an X image, put it on your server, and adjust the CSS to point to it. There's an image referenced from the SimpleModal project page.

Comment: Also, if you are using ASP.NET, you need to use the appendTo option: $(element).modal({appendTo:'form'});

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that you are missing a `<script>` block to actually utilize/implement the modal plugin.

maybe something like this?

```
<script>
   $().ready({
       $('#basicModalContent').modal();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: OH man - i forgot to put the css files....<!-- Page styles --> 
    <link type='text/css' href='/Content/demo.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' /> 
 
    <!-- Contact Form CSS files --> 
    <link type='text/css' href='/Content/basic.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />

Comment: You cannot simply reference the modal.js file without ever telling it what it should be applied to.  Look at the code snippet in the answer.

Comment: @jerrold , thats why always keep firebug open , it will tell you all the errors.